# How can a pinhole camera perceive depth ?

Tags: opencv, camera, depth

i am new to opencv and I want to use a pinhole camera to estimate depth in an image. How is that possible ? I mean can I achieve it Or do I need two cameras or some other sensors ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is no. If the only thing you have is single image there is no way to tell depth of a single pixel in that image.

You can use structure from motion to build a depth map if you would have an video instead of an image. This uses a difference in consequential frames to estimate the depth.

See http://www.morethantechnical.com/2012/02/07/structure-from-motion-and-3d-reconstruction-on-the-easy-in-opencv-2-3-w-code/

Comment: Yes , I do have an image sequence (video) . This link looks very helpful thanks a lot !